# mysql / query / group by for notification

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, notifications, subquery

Here's my problem, I am looking to manage notification on state changes.

I need a query specifying a state change between time t and the last notification.

Both queries are made but I can not manage a comprehensive application including the condition.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa29b/1

In the example given,

Server_id = 18 - 18:00 2014-04-16 and 2014-04-16 5:15 p.m., PLOSS is equal, no change, I do not send the notification

Server_id = 25 - 18:00 2014-04-16 and 2014-04-16 5:55 p.m., PLOSS is different, change information, I sent a notification and put a day 25 - 6:00 p.m. for 2014-04-16 1 notification for the next queries.

Answer (score 0):

i think you made a typo for you 2 lines sample.
Could it be possible, in your application, to record each change/insert in a dedicated table ?
Then daily,hourly (or vwhatever) process to read if there was some change, can be based on this "change pointer" table